# CakePHP and HTTP/Request2

Tags: php, cakephp, httprequest

I am building a web application and need to connect to a third party API.
The example code provided by the third party uses HTTP/Request2 to connect.

I know that I could use curl to connect but I would prefer to use the method that was provided to me.

I have tried to add:

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

to my controller, but when I run it I get the error:

> Error: Class 'HttpSocket' not found

I have tried to find examples of how to use HttpSocket with cakePHP, where/how to add it to the controller.

this is my controller:

```
class RequestsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
        $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CakePHP version?  The way you're trying to include HttpSocket should be correct for older versions of cake, http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Utility-Libraries/HttpSocket.html, but has changed for newer versions of cake.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html

Comment: I am using 2.4.2 I have already seen the link you sent to the cookbook  but I still have not managed to implement it correctly

Comment: @Ronnyvdb Where in the documentation did you see this wrong approach? Can you link to the source? I bet you have not been reading the correct manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 2.4.2, you should not be using App::import, but App::uses, as written in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html (the second link I posted)  for versions 2.+. I usually put App::uses as the top of the file, above the class declaration, but you can call it wherever, as long as it's loaded before you reference it.

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```